# SharePoint enumerating all managed paths using the Client Object Model (COM)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint, com

Is there a way to enumerate all managed paths for a specified Site Collection using the Client Object Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have access to SharePoint Administration functionality from Client Object Model. So the answer is "No", you cannot enumerate managed paths from CSOM.
Of course you can create custom web service which will expose this information and deploy it to SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at incorporating a small powershell script to do this.